# Check that text is visible Selenium + Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Here is HTML:

```
<select size="1" id="F_21__3" class="c3" style="position: absolute; left: 127px; top: 173px; width: 148px; height: 14px; font-style: normal; font-weight: normal; text-decoration: none; text-shadow: none; font-stretch: normal;" disabled="disabled">
    <option value="I" des="Item">Item</option>
    <option value="S" des="Service">Service</option>
</select>
```

[image: img]

How to check that text "Service" is visible with Selenium + Java?

Comment: Is it always disabled? When will it be enabled? After some action?

Comment: Please post the code where you attempted this and any error messages you received.

Answer (score 3):

Code to check if 'Services' is selected:

```
WebElement selectedByDefault= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='F_21__3']"));
Select select = new Select(selectedByDefault);
if(select.getFirstSelectedOption().equals("Service"))
{
    System.out.println("Services is displayed by Default.");
}
```

Comment: select tag is disabled. can we interact with disabled element? have you checked?

Comment: I didn't get a chance to deal with the disabled Select before, But in this case, we are not selecting anything. But only retrieving the selected value, it should have no issue with the element being disabled.

Comment: @Murthi I just tested it, this works just fine... have you checked?

Answer (score 0):

Code to check if text 'Service' is VISIBLE or not

```
 String checkTextVisible = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Service')]").getText();
if(checkTextVisible.equals("Service")){
   System.out.println(checkTextVisible + " text is visible");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not important if the field is disabled or enabled. You just find the correct selector and after that you can check it very easy.

```
String actualText = driver.findElemeny(By.cssSelector("yourSelector")).getAttribut("value");
Assert.assertEqual(actualText, "Service");
```

or more simple (but only if Service don't appear in another place on your page).

```
boolean presence = false;
if(driver.getPageSource().contains("Service")){
System.out.println("Text is present");
presence = true;
}else{
System.out.println("Text is absent");}

Assert.assertTrue(presence);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getFirstSelectedOption()` to get the visible selected dropdown.

```
@Findby(id="F_21__3")
private WebElement selectID;

Select s = new Select(selectID);
   String selected = s.getFirstSelectedOption().getText();
   Assert.assertTrue(selected.equals("Service"));
```

Answer (score -3):

If you want to check if "Service" selected or not, code below will return true/false:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='F_21__3']/option[.='Service']")).isSelected()
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I just tested it. It reports all of the `OPTION`s as displayed whether they are the default selected value or not.

Comment: The first code block is NOT correct because it returns `true` whether 'Service' or 'Item' is selected.